# How to solve Syntax Error in Data Statement?

Tags: fortran

Hi I am new here and want to solve this problem:

```
do k=1,31
    Data H(1,k)/0/
End do

do l=1,21
   Data H(l,1)/0.5*(l-1)/
End do

do m=31,41
   Data H(17,m)/0/
End do

do n=17,21
   Data H(n,41)/0.5*(n-17)/
End do
```

I get error for l and n saying that it is a syntax error in DATA statement. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the error message you get?  And what is it you are trying to do?  That is, why do you want to use `data` statements here rather than assignment?

Comment: data statements must appear before any executable code, so cant be in a loop

Comment: @agentp That is not correct, even in Fortran 2008/2015.

Comment: Jason, what compiler?

Answer (score 1):

You have three problems here, and not just with the "`l`" and "`n`" loops.

The first problem is that the values in a `data` statement cannot be arbitrary expressions.  In particular, they must be constants; `0.5*(l-1)` is not a constant.

The second problem is that the bounds in the object lists must also be constant (expressions); `l` is not a constant expression.

For the first, it's also worth noting that `*` in a data value list has a special meaning, and it isn't the multiplication operator.  `*` gives a repeat count, and a repeat count of `0.5` is not valid.

You can fix the second point quite simply, by using such constructions as

```
data H(1,1:31) /31*0./  ! Note the repeat count specifier
```

outside a loop, or using an implied loop

```
data (H(1,k),k=1,31) /31*0./
```

To do something for the "`l`" loop is more tedious

```
data H(1:21,1) /0., 0.5, 1., 1.5, ... /
```

and we have to be very careful about the number of values specified.  This cannot be dynamic.

The third problem is that you cannot specify explicit initialization for an element more than once.  Look at your first two loops: if this worked you'd be initializing `H(1,1)` twice.  Even though the same value is given, this is still invalid.

Well, actually you have four problems.  The fourth is related to the point about dynamic number of values.  You probably don't want to be doing explicit initialization.  Whilst it's possible to do what it looks like you want to do, just use assignment where these restrictions don't apply.

```
do l=1,21
   H(l,1) = 0.5*(l-1)
End do
```

Yes, there are times when complicated explicit initialization is a desirable thing, but in this case, in what I assume is new code, keeping things simple is good.  An "initialization" portion of your code which does the assignments is far more "modern".